# How do I access values created by serializeArray in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, serializearray

I have this HTML:

```
<form id='myform'>
<input name='title' value='foo'/>
</form>
```

And I create an object array from it like this:

```
var dataArray = $("#myform").serializeArray();
```

Now how do I access 'title' in dataArray? This does not work:

```
alert(dataArray['title']);
alert(dataArray['title'].val());
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Similar to what Nick posted, but a little cleaner

```
var dataArray = $("#myform").serializeArray(),
    dataObj = {};

$(dataArray).each(function(i, field){
  dataObj[field.name] = field.value;
});
```

Then access the same way

```
alert(dataObj['title']);
```

Answer (score 30):

You can either loop through, [as @Tom has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236768/how-do-i-access-values-created-by-serializearray-in-jquery/4236777#4236777)...or if you're accessing more than one, be a bit more efficient and loop once, creating an object like this:

```
var dataArray = $("#myform").serializeArray(),
    len = dataArray.length,
    dataObj = {};

for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
  dataObj[dataArray[i].name] = dataArray[i].value;
}
```

Then you can access it like you want, for example:

```
alert(dataObj['title']); //or alert(dataObj.title);
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6wYQS/).

Answer (score 16):

```
alert(dataArray[0].name);
alert(dataArray[0].value);
```

So:

```
for (i=0; i<dataArray.length; i += 1) {
    if (dataArray[i].name === "title") {
        // do something here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have multiple input fields and I don't want to rely on the order?

Comment: You're not relying on order the name is the id and the value is the value, they're just not in an object like you were expecting, you'll need to iterate over the array and process the things as you encounter them.

Answer (score 4):

Adding this anyway to help others in future. Good way to quickly inspect all values.

```
var formdata = $( "#myform" ).serializeArray();
var formdata = JSON.stringify(formdata);
alert (formdata);
```

Answer (score 3):

Run `console.log(dataArray);`, then open up the property inspector, and check the console. In Chrome, you'd right click and select "Inspect Element" and then click the ">=" looking icon in the bottom left, it's the second from the left.

In Firefox you'd install firebug and there's a tab called "Console"

Not sure if it's available in IE, probably something in the developer tools (press <kbd>f12</kbd>) but i wouldn't recommend developing in IE.

Anyway this will list out the object in a way that allows you to navigate and see the values of each item. That way you can then use this to decipher how to access the values :)

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

append/echo/print `dataArray[0].name` to a div will give you 'title'

Answer (score 2):

Alerting serializeArray of inputs in myDiv (note: the `:input` selector will include select and textarea tags as well!):

```
//alert(fData.length) // how many inputs got picked up 
var fData=$("#myDiv :input").serializeArray();
var msg=""; 
for(var i=0;i<fData.length;i++){
    var raKy=Object.keys(fData[i]); 
    msg+="\n"+raKy[0]+":"+eval("fData[i]."+raKy[0])+" "+raKy[1]+":"+eval("fData[i]."+raKy[1]); 
}
alert(msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

## With `uderscore.js`, this is how we can go about it:

```js
var serializedArray = $('form#spiderman-application').serializeArray();

var serializedObject = _.object(
  _.pluck(serializedArray, 'name'), 
  _.pluck(serializedArray, 'value')
)

console.log(serializedObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>

<form id="spiderman-application">
  <legend>Application Form</legend>
  <input name="./fname" value="Peter" />
  <input name="./lname" value="Parker" />
</form>
```

Good Luck...